# Malloc & calloc: different memory size allocated

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, calloc

So, I have this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *p;
    long n = 1;

    while(1) {
        p = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
        //p = calloc(n, sizeof(char));

        if(p) {
            printf("[%ld] Memory allocation successful! Address: %p\n", n , p);
            n++;
         } else {
            printf("No more memory! Sorry...");
            break;
        }
    }

    free(p);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And I run in on Windows. Interesting thing:

- if we use malloc, the program allocates about 430 MB of memory and then stops (photo here => https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYg75.png)
- if we use calloc, the program allocates about 2 GB of memory and then stops (photo here => https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqGQX.png)
- (strange test): if we use both of them in the same time, it uses maximum of (~400MB + ~2GB) / 2 => ~1.2GB

However, if I run the same code on Linux, the allocation goes on and on (after 600k allocations and many GB used it still continues until eventually it is killed) and approximately the same amount of memory is used.

So my question is: shouldn't they allocate the same amount of memory? I thought the only difference was that calloc initialize the memory with zero (malloc returns uninitialized memory). And why it only happens on Windows? It's strange and interesting in the same time.

Hope you can help me with an explanation for this. Thanks!

Edit:

- Code::Blocks 13.12 with GNU GCC Compiler
- Windows 10 (x64)
- Linux Mint 17.2 "Rafaela" - Cinnamon (64-bit) (for Linux testing)

Comment: There's a difference between *virtual* memory allocated and *physical* memory allocated... and also between how the two operating systems handle, and display, such memory allocations.

Comment: What is the practical use of such a test?

Comment: We were studying memory allocation at the university at the programming course and I just wanted to see how everything works. I wrote this program just to see how fast my memory is filling up (I have 8GB Ram but in Windows maxium of 2GB is used with this program - another thing I noticed).

Comment: You should be more precise about the environment: which compiler? 32 or 64 bits? which version of Windows and Linux...

Comment: I added these details at the end of the post.

Comment: Try adding `memset(p,0, n)` right alfter `malloc`. Then you should get the same result as with the `calloc` version. `calloc` clears the allocated memory, but `malloc` doesn't.

Comment: Michael, you're right, it's working like this. Thanks you too for "enlightening" me. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the program output, you actually allocate the same number of blocks, `65188` for `malloc`, `65189` for `calloc`.  Ignoring overhead, that's slightly less than 2GB of memory.

My guess is that you compile in 32 bit mode (pointers are dumped as 32 bits), which limits the amount of memory available to a single user process to less than 2GB.  The difference on the process map display comes from how your program uses the memory it allocates.

The `malloc` version does not touch the allocated pages: more than 3 quarters of them are not actually mapped, hence *only* 430MB.

The `calloc` version shows 2GB of *mapped* memory: chances are your C library function `calloc` clears the allocated memory, even for pages obtained from the OS. This is not optimal, but only visible if you do not touch the allocated memory, a special case anyway.  Yet it would be faster to not clear pages obtained from the OS as they are specified to be zero filled anyway.

In Linux, you may be compiling to 64 bits, getting access to much more than 2GB of virtual process space.  Since you do not touch the memory, it is not mapped, and the same seems to happen in the `calloc` case as well.  The C runtime is different (64 bit `glibc` on Linux, 32 bit Microsoft Library on Windows).  You should use `top` or `ps` in a different terminal in Linux to check how much memory is actually mapped to your process in both cases.

Comment: `calloc` definitly zero fills the allocated memory whereas `malloc` doesnt.

Comment: @MichaelWalz On Linux, the `calloc` doesn't force allocation of the physical memory - as long as it is not touched, it stays virtual. Just like `malloc`. Did test precisely that about few weeks ago.

Comment: @Dummy00001 strange, many docs for `calloc` including [this one](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) state that `calloc` zero fills the allocated memory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was compiling in 32 bit mode so I'll try to compile the code in 64 bit mode and see what's happening.  Nice explanation for the rest :) Have a nice day!

Comment: @MichaelWalz: `calloc` does not need to clear memory it just mapped from the OS if `mmap` is specified as returning zero filled pages, or more precisely if the pages will be filled with 0 when they eventuelly get mapped.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: the C Standard says: 7.22.3.3 *The calloc function allocates space for an array of nmemb objects, each of whose size is size. The space is initialized to all bits zero.*  If `calloc` uses a system call that returns a block of memory guaranteed to be 0 filled when mapped, it does not need to waste time filling it explicitly with `memset`.

Comment: @chqrlie that sounds reasonable. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, yes, as @chqrlie has explained. C standard is portable and has no concept of the virtual memory. How OS chooses to "fill" or "initialize" the memory, is irrelevant to the standard. Years ago, Linux/glibc used always normal `memset()` on the `calloc`ed memory (which forced physical memory allolcation) - but today they have optimized it to skip the `memset()`.